# How do I create multiple directories within a directory that's in a directory with a single line command

Tags: powershell

so my path is from the desktop and I tried: mkdir OS\LAB1\Finance,Public,Archive,Customer
The command makes the first 3 directories but the last three get made on my desktop and not within LAB1,how do I do it with one command line?
Thank you

Comment: `'Finance','Public','Archive','Customer' | % { mkdir "OS\LAB1\$_" }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is this the only way to do it? im still learning command lines and im not sure what some of the syntax means like %,{},$_.

Comment: `New-Item -Path 'Public','Archive','Customer' -ItemType Directory`. The catch is that the folders will be created in the current directory. Alternatively, using `mkdir`: `mkdir 'Public','Archive','Customer'`.

Answer (score 2):

not a one liner, but this does the trick

```
$folders = @(,'Public','Archive','Customer')
New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\OS\LAB1\Finance\ -Force
foreach($folder in $folders){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\OS\LAB1\Finance\$folder -Force
}
```

The force parameter creates all the directories in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to create 4 directories under LAB1 not a single directory four deep. in Bash you can do this.

```
for i in $(tr ',' '\n' <<< "Finance,Public,Archive,Customer"); do mkdir  "$i"; done
```

Result looks like this
0 drwxr-xr-x@   7 camerontownshend  staff   224 16 Mar 12:28 .
0 drwxr-xr-x@ 147 camerontownshend  staff  4704 16 Mar 11:13 ..
0 drwxr-xr-x@   2 camerontownshend  staff    64 16 Mar 12:28 Archive
0 drwxr-xr-x@   2 camerontownshend  staff    64 16 Mar 12:28 Customer
0 drwxr-xr-x    2 camerontownshend  staff    64 16 Mar 12:28 Finance
0 drwxr-xr-x@   2 camerontownshend  staff    64 16 Mar 12:28 Public

Explanation
for i in ... -> for loop
tr ',' '\n' -> replaces commas with new lines
do mkdir  "$i" done -> run whatever is inside the do/done pair. The mkdir "$i" - substitutes the iterator from the loop as a variable into the mkdir command

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple folders (full paths) in one line using a list (caution: no spaces after commas):

```bash
$ mkdir -p /tmp/{test1,test2}
```

To verify:

```bash
$ ls /tmp/test*
/tmp/test1:
/tmp/test2:
```